# Approximation of an expression (no calculator please!)

Tags: approximation

Today I had my college admission exam, It was good, but there was a question which I found a bit interesting (but unable to solve at the moment). It says,

> **Question**: Find the positive integer which is *just equal* to the expression
>   $$(1+0.0001)^{10000}$$
>
> 1. **3**
> 2. **4**
> 3. **5**
> 4. **6**

Well, I tried this with binomial, even with limits, but no solid deduction till yet. Any way to get out with this one?

**Note:** Not a homework question!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is approximately e for n large.

Comment: @Paul, you might as well post that as an answer... (possibly with an estimate of the error)

Comment: @A.P. not an answer points junkie!:)

Comment: @Paul The point is not reputation. If you post an answer, then the OP can accept it. Otherwise it will regularly pop-up on the front page.

Comment: The answer is none of the above, as the expression does not evaluate to a integer.

Comment: I don't understand the question: The expression does not evaluate to an integer.

Comment: @A.P. OK, good point. Too busy at the mo & as said, it isn't terribly close to 3!

Comment: For the record, according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281+%2B+10%5E%28-4%29%29%5E%2810%5E4%29) the number in question is about $2.7181459 \dotsc$, so definitely not an integer...

Comment: @Paul Thanks! I didn't know that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I guess from the phrase "just equal to" they meant that we will be needing a minor approximation. Although answer approximation isn't  that much minor. You can freely blame the question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the binomial expansion, which approximates the sum of reciprocals of the factorials: $$(1+0.0001)^{10000} = 1^{10000}+10000\times0.0001+{10000\times9999\over2}\times0.0001^2+{10000\times9999\times9998\over2\times3}\times0.0001^3+{10000\times9999\times9998\times9997\over2\times3\times4}\times0.0001^4+...\simeq1+1+1/2+1/6+1/24+1/120\simeq 3$$

Also there is the (well-known?) expression for the number $e$:
$$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n$$
and $$e\simeq 3$$

Comment: Seriously, one needs great persistence to attempt this one with the first method, I even tried it but dropped it in the mid-way thinking that this would take took long. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Observe that your number is $f(10^4)$, where
$$
f(n) := \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right)^n
$$
and recall that $e = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(n)$. Further, observe that $f(n)$ is strictly increasing for $n>1$, therefore $f(10^4) < e \approx 2.71828$.

---

If you don't already know that $f(n)$ is increasing, you could prove it by recalling that $\log(1 + \frac{1}{x}) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$ and noting that
$$
\begin{gather}
n \left( \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{2n^2} \right) < (n+1) \left( \frac{1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{2(n+1)^2} \right) \\
1 - \frac{1}{2n} < 1 - \frac{1}{2(n+1)}
\end{gather}
$$

Answer (score 0):

there is no positive integer that is equal to $ (1+0.0001)^{10000}$ because 
$$2 < (1+0.0001)^{10000} < e < 3.$$ this follows for two reasons: (a) $(1+\frac 1 x)^x$ is an increasing function, (b) $\lim_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac 1 x)^x = e.$